# Using a Radio Button Group in an Editor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have an Editor Template for a model that I created. It has several other fields on it, but the one that is giving me trouble is the radio button. I create the radio button like so:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.EVote, true)
```

When it outputs the Radio Buttons I get this. Which have different names so they arent a radio group.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ApproveVote field is required." id="FinalApproval_0__EVote" name="FinalApproval[0].EVote" type="radio" value="True">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ApproveVote field is required." id="FinalApproval_0__EVote" name="FinalApproval[0].EVote" type="radio" value="True">
```

So how do I make my model create a radio group for these radio buttons? I have tried adding the HTML attribute of `name = "FinalNames"` and MVC overrides the name and continues to use its naming standard.

Answer (score 4):

To add your radio buttons to a group you could change your code to:

```
@Html.RadioButton("GROUPNAMEHERE", "LABEL", BOOLVALUEFORCHECKED)
```

Not sure if you actually need the RadioButtonFor in this instance.

EDIT: If you do need RadioButtonFor, try this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.EVote, true, new { Name = "GROUPNAME" })
```

Comment: I had actually already tried that. The problem still is that when using an editor template apparently asp.net ignores the name you supplied and continue using it own.

Comment: Group isnt a valid HTML Attribute it has to be name, that's how Radio Group work is it looks for other radio buttons with the name and then forces only one selection from that group. You would think you could use the `new { name = "someName" }` in the HTMLAtrributes parameter but again asp.net just ignores this.

Comment: Figured it out, with a little help from you, +1. While HTML attributes arent case specific when in HTML documents, when using the RadioButton or RadioButtonFor you have to specify name as uppercase ie `new { Name = "SomeName" }` otherwise it ignores it and uses its naming convention.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought I made a mistake. Group looked weird after I typed it. Let me edit that.